# Does $\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} \frac{-1^ksin(k^{100})}{k^{3/2}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the following sum, and determine if it converges: $\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^ksin(k^{100})}{k^{3/2}}$

I was thinking of using the comparison test, and realizing that the numerator is bounded by $-1<x<1$. Thus, I was going to test the limit on $\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}$ or $-\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}$. I know that the harmonic series diverges, and so I am inclined to believe that this series also diverges.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum%5E%7B%2B%5Cinfty%7D_%7Bk%3D1%7D+%5Cfrac%7B-1%5Eksin(k%5E%7B100%7D)%7D%7Bk%5E%7B3%2F2%7D%7D

Comment: This says 'by the comparison test, the series converges'. Was my use of the comparison test correct?

Answer (score 1):

The series has absolute convergence + integral test:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^k\sin(k^{100})}{k^{3/2}}\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{3/2}}\text{ converges}\iff\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^{3/2}}dx\text{ converges}$$

Apply the term test to show the series cannot diverge by oscillation:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\sin(k^{100})}{k^{3/2}}=0$$

Thus, it converges.

Comment: "$\implies\int \implies$..." what do you mean here?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Oh, right, wrong symbols.  Fixed

Comment: It's still unclear, $\int \iff \text {something}$ does not make sense! "$\int f$" is  not a logical formula. Perhaps the first $\iff$ should be a $\leq$ or something...?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Hm, I meant to say that the sum converges iff the $\int$ converges.  Is that right now?

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1}\left| \frac{-1^k\sin(k^{100})}{k^{3/2}}\right| <\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}=\zeta{(3/2)}$$
so the series converges

Comment: This technically doesn't show that the sum converges, just that it doesn't diverge to $\infty$. We can't apply the direct comparison test until we talk about absolute convergence.

Comment: @Valborg I think the the comparison test very clear

Comment: Except the direct comparison test only works on series with non-negative terms. We must pass through absolute convergence first.

Comment: I guarantee you some calculus student is going to see this answer and later erroneously conclude that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k$ converges by direct comparison with $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$. The comparison test is often introduced before absolute convergence, hence, it is typically not phrased in terms of absolute convergence. My point is that while *we* know what you mean, we are not your *audience*.

Comment: Yeah, the point your critics want to make is that by this argument $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{-1}k$ would also converge because $-1/k<1/k^{3/2}$. First conclude that it converges absolutely, and therefore it converges.

Comment: "direct comparison test only works on series with non-negative terms" that only means if a term with positive terms diverger we can't  assume a term with mixed terms will too.  (Obviously $\sum (-1)^k 1/k$ converges). If a series with positive terms converges then obviously any other series with equal magnituted terms but maybe mised sinage will converg.

Comment: At the end you want to say "so the series converges absolutely, hence converges".

Answer (score 0):

For any $n$,
$|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k|
\le \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|
$
by the triangle inequality.

Therefore,
if
$a_k \to 0$,
and
$\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|$
converges as
$n \to \infty$,
so does
$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k
$.

This applies here.

Comment: You basically resaid my answer.  :(